# How can I move a changeset from a remotely deleted branch to another branch?

Tags: mercurial

So someone deleted a remote branch, but a changeset was lost when he deleted the branch.

I have the changeset on my local repository and tried to merge the changeset to my default branch, then I pushed, but I got an error "abort: push creates new remote head 650367cd0ff4 on branch 'rc'!"

Comment: What do you mean by branch deletion? All commits of this branch were stripped or branch was closed with `--close-branch` or something else?

Comment: I don't know what he did, but I don't have access to it and the deletion was intentional. Does the method change the resolution to my problem of cherry picking a changeset from a local branch that no longer exists on remote, to a new branch that exists on both?

Comment: Does the deleted branch is named "rc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options, depending on the situation you have:

1. If the whole branch was stripped and you have that branch locally then you can push it again:

   ```
   hg push --new-branch
   ```

   This is recommended, because Mercurial will anyway send your local commits to remote repo every time you will do push (until you strip these commits locally). You can then *close unwanted branch* with `--close-branch` (this will leave all commits in repo, but just mark branch as closed/unused).

   ```
   hg ci --close-branch
   ```
2. Graft the wanted commit locally from some branch to other:

   ```
   hg graft -r 123
   hg push
   ```
3. Create new remote head ("abort: push creates new remote head 650367cd0ff4 on branch 'rc'!"). It's nothing wrong, it just means that one of your branches will have two separate top commits. These commits can be merged together later.

   ```
   hg push -f
   ```

Comment: Haha ya I suppose I could just hg push -f
Thanks for your help!